# How to parse SQL Server String in hour, min and second

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, date, parsing

I have time stored as `PT1H22M59.551S`.
There it reads read 1 hour 22 min and 59.551 sec.

What is the most efficient way to split this?

Data could be like this. So no separator is mandatory

```
PT0S
PT6H4M29.212S
PT0S
PT2M55.126S
PT54M4.12S
PT3H6M5.74S
PT16H27M52.069S
```

Comment: What have you tried? SQL Server has a bunch of helpful functions to assist you.

Comment: I posted what i had  tried as my own answer  but answer of @TappDev60193 seems better. Obviously , it was possible to solve that but i wanted to use most efficient way and yes, i should have posted what i tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create a function to perform the conversion with basic text manipulation:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f_GetTime(@TimeInput VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS TIME
AS BEGIN
    SET @TimeInput = REPLACE(REPLACE(@TimeInput, 'PT', ''), 'S', '')
    IF CHARINDEX('H', @TimeInput) = 0 -- Add missing H
        SET @TimeInput = '0H' + @TimeInput
    IF CHARINDEX('M', @TimeInput) = 0 -- Add missing M
        SET @TimeInput = REPLACE(@TimeInput, 'H', 'H0M')
    RETURN CONVERT(TIME, REPLACE(REPLACE(@TimeInput, 'H', ':'), 'M', ':'))
END
GO
```

Then you can use it with just scalar queries:

```
SELECT dbo.f_GetTime('PT1H22M59.551S') AS TimeValue
```

Or you can use it with tables:

```
DECLARE @Input TABLE (TimeInput VARCHAR(20))
INSERT @Input VALUES ('PT1H22M59.551S'), ('PT0S'), ('PT6H4M29.212S'), ('PT0S'),
    ('PT2M55.126S'), ('PT54M4.12S'), ('PT3H6M5.74S'), ('PT16H27M52.069S')
SELECT TimeInput, dbo.f_GetTime(TimeInput) AS TimeValue FROM @Input
```

This would return:

```
TimeInput            TimeValue
-------------------- ----------------
PT1H22M59.551S       01:22:59.5510000
PT0S                 00:00:00.0000000
PT6H4M29.212S        06:04:29.2120000
PT0S                 00:00:00.0000000
PT2M55.126S          00:02:55.1260000
PT54M4.12S           00:54:04.1200000
PT3H6M5.74S          03:06:05.7400000
PT16H27M52.069S      16:27:52.0690000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--sql server
declare @data table(
    lineid int identity, 
    a varchar(100),
    b varchar(100),
    hr varchar(20),
    [minute] varchar(20),
    [second] varchar(20)
)
insert @data(a) select 'PT0S'
insert @data(a) select 'PT6H4M29.212S'
insert @data(a) select 'PT0S'
insert @data(a) select 'PT2M55.126S'
insert @data(a) select 'PT54M4.12S'
insert @data(a) select 'PT3H6M5.74S'
insert @data(a) select 'PT16H27M52.069S'

update @data
    set b = replace(a,'PT','')

update @data
    set hr = LEFT(b,charindex('H',b))

update @data
    set b = REPLACE(b,hr,'')

update @data
    set [minute] = LEFT(b,charindex('M',b))

update @data
    set b = REPLACE(b,[minute],'')

update @data
    set [second] = LEFT(b,charindex('S',b))

update @data
    set b = REPLACE(b,[second],'')

update @data
    set [hr] = REPLACE([hr],'H',''),[minute]=REPLACE([minute],'M',''),[second]=REPLACE([second],'S','')

update @data
    set hr = isnull(nullif(hr,''),'0'),[minute] = isnull(nullif([minute],''),'0'),[second] = isnull(nullif([second],''),'0')

select *,
    [hr] + ' hour'+ case when hr <> '1' then 's ' else ' ' end +
    [minute] + ' minute'+ case when [minute] <> '1' then 's ' else ' ' end +
    [second] + ' second(s)'
from @data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    --sql server
    declare @data table(
        lineid int identity, 
        [inboundTime] varchar(100)


    )
    insert @data([inboundTime]) select 'PT0S'
    insert @data([inboundTime]) select 'PT6H4M29.212S'
    insert @data([inboundTime]) select 'PT0S'
    insert @data([inboundTime]) select 'PT2M55.126S'
    insert @data([inboundTime]) select 'PT54M4.12S'
    insert @data([inboundTime]) select 'PT3H6M5.74S'
    insert @data([inboundTime]) select 'PT16H27M52.069S'
    insert @data([inboundTime]) select 'PT52.069S'

      update @data
        set [inboundTime] = replace([inboundTime],'PT','')

    SELECT  

             INBOUND_H
          ,  INBOUND_M
          ,  INBOUND_S
          ,  INBOUND_H*3600 + INBOUND_M*60  inboundTimeMin
          , [inboundTime]
    from (
    SELECT  

            IIF (   CHARINDEX('H', [inboundTime]) > 0 ,   SUBSTRING([inboundTime],  0, CHARINDEX('H', [inboundTime])),0)  INBOUND_H
          , IIF (   CHARINDEX('M', [inboundTime]) > 0 ,    SUBSTRING([inboundTime], CHARINDEX('H', [inboundTime])+1,CHARINDEX('M', [inboundTime]) - CHARINDEX('H', [inboundTime])-1 ), 0) INBOUND_M
          , SUBSTRING([inboundTime], CHARINDEX('M', [inboundTime])+1,CHARINDEX('S', [inboundTime]) - CHARINDEX('M', [inboundTime])-1 ) INBOUND_S
          , [inboundTime]
  
      FROM @data)x
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more robust function built off solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f_GetTime(@TimeInput VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS BEGIN
    SET @TimeInput = REPLACE(REPLACE(@TimeInput, 'PT', ''), 'S', '')
    IF CHARINDEX('H', REVERSE(@TimeInput)) = 1
        SET @TimeInput = @TimeInput + '00:00' -- Add missing S
    IF CHARINDEX('M', REVERSE(@TimeInput)) = 1
        SET @TimeInput = @TimeInput + '00' -- Add missing S
    IF CHARINDEX('H', @TimeInput) = 0 -- Add missing H
        SET @TimeInput = '00H' + @TimeInput
    IF CHARINDEX('M', @TimeInput) = 0 -- Add missing M
        SET @TimeInput = REPLACE(@TimeInput, 'H', 'H0M')
    RETURN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), REPLACE(REPLACE(@TimeInput, 'H', ':'), 'M', ':'))
END
GO
```